# What is this database error in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I got the following error in codeigniter

Error Number: 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `appID` = 'buttn_default'' at line 2

SELECT `responseURL` WHERE `appID` = 'buttn_default'
```

This is my modal function which im using to get the data from the database

```
function get_response_url($appID, $merchant_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('responseURL');
        $this->db->from('response_urls');
        $this->db->where('appID',$appID);
        //$this->db->or_where('merchant_id',$merchant_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            return $row->responseURL;
        }
    else
        {
            $appID='buttn_default';
            $this->db->select('responseURL');
            $this->db->where('appID',$appID);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if($query->num_rows() == 1)
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            return $row->responseURL;
        }

    }
```

Why doesnt this work.why am I gettign this error.

Comment: What data type is `appID` in your related database table?

Comment: Can active the profiler to get the Query, there is something wrong with the values

Comment: @summea DATA type is varchar

Comment: I ave this value in the database

Comment: Oh, is this happening in the `else` statement? You'd need a `from` for that, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mysql error shows that there is no from clause and your else part is also missing with `from()` function of active record

```
else
    {
        $appID='buttn_default';
        $this->db->select('responseURL');
        $this->db->from('table_name_here');  <------
        $this->db->where('appID',$appID);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        return $row->responseURL;
    }
```